# trying to get my eventwatcher program to only pick up when a new instance of notepad has opened

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been working on a C# forms program that will pick up when a program has started and when one has closed. I'm able to get the program to pick up when anything opens and when they close. This is the part where I'm stuck I need to try and make it only pick up specific things like notepad, Microsoft word, google chrome, Etc. Iv tried using

```
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
```

but for some reason, I just cant get it to work right. ill add an image of what the program currently looks like when running

[image: processRunningImage]

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        struct APPINFO
        {

        }

        private readonly List<APPINFO> currentlyRunningProcesses = new List<APPINFO>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ManagementEventWatcher AppStartQuery = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
            ManagementEventWatcher AppStopQuery = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"));

            AppStartQuery.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(StartedProcess);
            AppStartQuery.Start();


            AppStopQuery.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(StoppedProcess);
            AppStopQuery.Start();


            Console.WriteLine("Exit");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        private void StartedProcess(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var processStart = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["processID"].Value.ToString()));
                int processID = Process.GetProcessById(processStart.Id).Id;
                string processName = Process.GetProcessById(processStart.Id).ProcessName;
                string name = "Process Name: ";

                if (processName == "SnippingTool")
                {
                    ProcessStart.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessStart.Text = ProcessStart.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + name.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@" ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                else if (processName == "notepad")
                {
                    ProcessStart.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessStart.Text = ProcessStart.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + name.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@" ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                else if (processName == "chrome")
                {
                    ProcessStart.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessStart.Text = ProcessStart.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + name.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@" ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                else if (processName == "firefox")
                {
                    ProcessStart.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessStart.Text = ProcessStart.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + name.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@" ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
               

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start Process Exception: " + ee.Message);
            }
        }

        

        private void StoppedProcess(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                
                int processID = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessID"].Value.ToString());
                string processName = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString();
                string namee = "Process Name: ";
                if(processName == "notepad.exe")
                {
                    ProcessStop.Invoke(new Action(() => { ProcessStop.Text = ProcessStop.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ") 
                        + namee.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@"   ID:0") + Environment.NewLine; }));

                }
                else if(processName == "SnippingTool.e")
                {
                    ProcessStop.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                        ProcessStop.Text = ProcessStop.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + namee.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@"   ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                else if(processName == "chrome.exe")
                {
                 ProcessStop.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                        ProcessStop.Text = ProcessStop.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + namee.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@"   ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                else if(processName == "firefox.exe")
                {
                ProcessStop.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                        ProcessStop.Text = ProcessStop.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + namee.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@"   ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                /*ProcessStop.Invoke(new Action(() => 
                {
                    ProcessStop.Text = ProcessStop.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                    + namee.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@"   ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                }));*/


            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Stop Process Exception: " + ee.Message);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I was able to get the process to show only when notepads are open. But I can't get it to display whenever a notepad is closed. I used if statements to make the program only show notepad. I have updated the code above to show what I'm using currently

Comment: I was able to figure out the last issue with it not working on showing up on ended processes I had to add the .exe or .e on some of the processes to show up

Answer (score 0):

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        struct APPINFO
        {

        }

        private readonly List<APPINFO> currentlyRunningProcesses = new List<APPINFO>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ManagementEventWatcher AppStartQuery = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
            ManagementEventWatcher AppStopQuery = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"));

            AppStartQuery.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(StartedProcess);
            AppStartQuery.Start();


            AppStopQuery.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(StoppedProcess);
            AppStopQuery.Start();


            Console.WriteLine("Exit");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        private void StartedProcess(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var processStart = Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["processID"].Value.ToString()));
                int processID = Process.GetProcessById(processStart.Id).Id;
                string processName = Process.GetProcessById(processStart.Id).ProcessName;
                string name = "Process Name: ";

                if (processName == "SnippingTool")
                {
                    ProcessStart.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessStart.Text = ProcessStart.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + name.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@" ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                else if (processName == "notepad")
                {
                    ProcessStart.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessStart.Text = ProcessStart.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + name.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@" ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                else if (processName == "chrome")
                {
                    ProcessStart.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessStart.Text = ProcessStart.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + name.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@" ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                else if (processName == "firefox")
                {
                    ProcessStart.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        ProcessStart.Text = ProcessStart.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + name.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@" ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
               

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start Process Exception: " + ee.Message);
            }
        }

        

        private void StoppedProcess(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                
                int processID = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessID"].Value.ToString());
                string processName = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString();
                string namee = "Process Name: ";
                if(processName == "notepad.exe")
                {
                    ProcessStop.Invoke(new Action(() => { ProcessStop.Text = ProcessStop.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ") 
                        + namee.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@"   ID:0") + Environment.NewLine; }));

                }
                else if(processName == "SnippingTool.e")
                {
                    ProcessStop.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                        ProcessStop.Text = ProcessStop.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + namee.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@"   ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                else if(processName == "chrome.exe")
                {
                 ProcessStop.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                        ProcessStop.Text = ProcessStop.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + namee.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@"   ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                else if(processName == "firefox.exe")
                {
                ProcessStop.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                        ProcessStop.Text = ProcessStop.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                        + namee.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@"   ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                    }));
                }
                /*ProcessStop.Invoke(new Action(() => 
                {
                    ProcessStop.Text = ProcessStop.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt | ")
                    + namee.ToString() + processName.ToString() + processID.ToString(@"   ID:0") + Environment.NewLine;
                }));*/


            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Stop Process Exception: " + ee.Message);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: If this is an answer, you probably should highlight the answer part.